# Drools: How to get return values from Condition in Decision tables?

Tags: drools

I have a Decision table in Drools and I'm trying to retrieve the return values of the Conditions (columns) that evaluates to see if a particular Rule (rows) is executed. May I know how if it's possible? Please find below for a simple example of my problem.

```
                     Condition 1 |  Condition 2 |  Condition 3   |   Condition 4
                      Age < 60     Employed=Yes   Owns a house=Yes   Single=Yes
Rule 1:                 YES                           YES
Rule 2:                 YES            NO                              YES
Rule 3:                 NO                            YES
```

Let's say if Rule 2 should be ideally executed and yet Rule 1 is executed, I would like to know the reason why Rule 1 was executed by obtaining the return values of the Condition 1 and 3 (whether it is true or false). Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

The DRL rule for your `Rule 1` would be something like

```
rule "Rule 1"
when
    Person( $age: age < 60, $owner: owner == true )
then
    ...( $age, $owner )...
end
```

and on the right hand side you have binding variables `$age` and `$owner` set to the actual values as contained in the `Person` fact. You can use Java code in an ACTION column in a decision table to do whatever you want with those values.

**Edit** If you need the values for the negative case, you'll have to use another rule

```
rule "Rule 2"
when
    Person( $age: age, $owner: owner,
            $age >= 60 || $owner == false )
then
    another_action...( $age, $owner )...
end
```

Most likely, you'll need to do some other action anyway.

Of course, individual rules for all four cases are also possible. Note that decision tables let you write rules for all four cases TT, TF, FT, FF. You can combine the action cells so you can define the action for TF FT FF in a single cell.

Comment: Hi laune, thanks for your reply, I really appreciate it. Unfortunately, my problem does not allow me to do the above mentioned since the ACTION column will be executed only if the CONDITION evaluates to true. What I'm interested in is actually to be able to retrieve the values when CONDITION evaluates to FALSE. Hence, I need to be able to retrieve the values in both success and failure scenarios.

Comment: Added something for the negative case.

Comment: That will be very complex, isn't it? This is assuming that I have a small number of rules and all the conditions will apply to all my rules and this is not the case. I have approximately 100 Conditions and that means creating one rule for 100! of possible scenarios.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. You should provide more background if you want to hear more than technical details from me. - A decision table is a technique for detecting "interesting" attribute combinations - nothing more, period. To determine facts that don't match any combination, one additional rule is sufficient. To determine the values of an object's attributes you don't need rules at all.